# obj\Debug\XPExplorerBar.dll' doesn't contain any UserControl types

Tags: dll

I downloaded some code from codeproject ... this allow me to have  an "Themed Windows XP style Explorer Bar" incorporated in my project -- when i build it -- everything is fine - but when i run the program a get a message like obj\Debug\XPExplorerBar.dll' doesn't contain any UserControl types. Can anyone help..

Answer (score 17):

Right-click on the project > Set as Startup Project.

Answer (score 1):

Similar trouble with VB Express 2010. I found the answer here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/60020f2b-7b53-433e-b8bb-bb9585499037

I forgot that you have to set the startup project to the project with your forms in it. Right-click on the project > Set as Startup Project.